# Pasting MSWord to WYSIWYG (Summernote) & Special Characters

Tags: html, fonts, character-encoding, summernote

How do I keep character's like apostrophes from getting converted to things like â€™ when copying text from a word file into a WYSIWYG like Summernote?  Another example is ® getting converted into Ã¢

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#summernote').on('summernote.paste', function (customEvent, nativeEvent) {
  //set time out--so we buy some time to summernote can be receive and select pasting text
    setTimeout(function () {
       //this is texteditor container in summernote
        $('.note-editable').selectText(); 
     //call removeFormat method to clear text
        $("#summernote").summernote("removeFormat");
    }, 100);

});`
```

Comment: please clarify your answer

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.